# How to find repeated items in a Google Sheets array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

**The problem:**

I'm essentially looking to do the opposite of what UNIQUE() does. Given a cell containing an array of names, I'm trying to populate another cell with a list of the duplicates. I have some data as follows:

```
 |    A     |         B       |        |   C  |
-+----------+-----------------+  Goal: +------+
1|a, b, c, d|a, a, b, c, c, d |        | a, c |
```

Cell `A1` has the function `join(", "; sort(unique(filter(<list of names>, <filter criteria>))))`. This is a list of unique names from a sign-in sheet, filtered by what they came in for help with.

Cell `B1` has the function `join(", "; sort(filter(<list of names>, <filter criteria>)))`, so the same thing but without unique. This cell is a list of names from a sign-in sheet, filtered by what they signed-in for help with.

Cell `C1` would ideally have a list of the things that appear more than once in cell `B1`.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried looking up ways to get the difference of the arrays, but everything seems to be aiming to subtract values from each other, or to remove the duplicates.

I've tried using match() to match values between `A1` and `B1`, but also to no avail.

I tried filtering `B1` by removing things in `A1`, but that always ends up removing everything, because every element in `B1` is in `A1` somewhere.

**Some thoughts:**

If there is a way to go through the elements in `A1` and for each one remove the first occurrence of it in `B1`, then list the unique elements of the result, that should get what I'm looking for, but I'm fairly new to all these formulas so I'm not sure if that's even possible.

If anyone needs any clarification or anything leave a comment and I'll add to the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula in cell C1:

`=JOIN(", ",TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", ")),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(SPLIT(B1,", "),SPLIT(A1,", "))))},"select Col1 where Col2>1")))`

Comment: This just about does it! The only thing is now I get output in `C1` as `First1, Last1, First2, Last2` for the first and last names, if you happen to know what to do for that. But otherwise it solved the problem as I had it posted, I was assuming it'd be the same for names, but I'll try messing around with it too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also this seems to work:

```
=JOIN(", ",unique(QUERY({QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1,", ",0)),"select *",0),QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1&", -",", ",0)),"select * offset 1",0)},"select Col2 where Col1 = Col2")))
```

Please, [look at example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hSvamwqup81UPtFQhRADmB3ahS8AeTM_nmoVRfttsR0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I got "Query completed with an empty output" here

Comment: I've adited the formula and added [examle file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hSvamwqup81UPtFQhRADmB3ahS8AeTM_nmoVRfttsR0/edit?usp=sharing). Does it work now?